# "lembrar" vs "recordar"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, vocabulário

Olá, estou a aprender português. Há muitos dicionários que dizem *recordar(-se)* e *lembrar(-se)* são sinónimos, mas *recordar* não parece usado muito (na língua falada). É uma forma mais formal / literária? Ou há uma diferença subtil entre as formas? Quando preciso dizer *recordar* em vez de *lembrar*?

Comment: Maybe like ["recall" vs. "remember"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154337/whats-the-difference-between-recall-and-remember)?

Answer (score 10):

Como dizes, há uma diferença de registo ("recordar" é mais formal). Mas há mais. "Recordar" está mais ligado à memória e portanto "lembrar" nem sempre é substituível:

1. Pronominalmente, quando significa "ter/trazer à atenção consciente", por oposição à memória (o oposto de alguém *se esquecer* de alguma coisa no sentido de distração/discuido):

   > (1) ***Lembrei-me** à última da hora que tinha comprar pão.* (não **recordei-me à última da hora*)
   >   (2) *Ninguém o fez porque ninguém **se lembrou** disso.* (=toda a gente se esqueceu)
   >   (3) Alguém **se lembra** de alguma coisa que falte?

   Quando é mais uma questão de **memória**, são substituíveis:

   > (4) *Não **me lembro/me recordo** de alguma vez ter dito isso.* (ter em memória)
   >   (5) *Dos mais velhos que **se recordam/se lembram**, para os mais novos que aprendem.*
2. Quando "lembrar" significa "ter a ideia de" (i.e., não como oposto de "esquecer por descuido", mas uma ideia original):

   > (6) *Ninguém o fez porque ninguém **se lembrou** disso.* (exemplo igual a (3), mas aqui =ninguém teve essa ideia)
   >   (7) *Agora **lembrou-se** de me vir para aqui chatear-me.*
   >   (8) *E nem **se lembrou** de fazer o que de imediato se impunha, ir visitar um bairro de maioria de cor...* (também pode ser interpretado com o significado anterior)

   A expressão *não lembra a* (=é-lhe impensável) é bastante idiomática e está provavelmente relacionada com este significado, embora o verbo não seja aí usado pronominalmente:

   > (9) *Isso não **lembra** nem ao menino Jesus/nem ao diabo/a ninguém.*
3. No uso não pronominal, quando *lembrar* é algo que se suscita noutras pessoas e tem uma componente de advertência, aviso ([significado 3. do Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)). A regência é "lembrar alguma coisa a alguém" ou "lembrar alguém de alguma coisa", dependendo se o foco está na pessoa ou não. Os exemplos do Aulete são bons:

   > (10) ***Lembrou** o empregado de suas obrigações.*
   >   (11) *O juiz **lembrou** ao jogador que na próxima falta seria expulso.*

   Frequentemente, não é fácil distinguir este significado do 4. (*mencionar (algo) a (alguém), para que não seja esquecido*), como nas frases seguintes:

   > (12) *A FAO não se cansa também de **lembrar** aos países considerados desenvolvidos que é do seu interesse melhorar as condições alimentares dos mais pobres.*
   >   (13) *Só que a FNE **lembra** que «os compromissos assumidos não podem ser prejudicados por cortes nos orçamentos».*
   >   (14) *Na anterior gestão, **lembrou**, «bastava o despacho do vereador, agora é necessária a aprovação do colectivos de vereadores».*

   Nestas frases, "recordar" é menos natural, mas possível. Se substituirmos por "recordar", arriscamos introduzir alguma ambiguidade. Por exemplo, em (14) pode passar a parecer o locutor estaria simplesmente a relembrar factos passados e não chamar o atenção do interlocutor para um facto como parte de algum argumento, embora geralmente o contexto esclareça a ambiguidade.
4. Relacionado com o ponto anterior, *lembrar* pode significar *sugerir*, *trazer  à memória por sugestão* ([significado 2. do Aulete Digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)):

   > (15) *O estilo do pintor **lembrava** o de Van Gogh.*
   >   (16) *Essa história **lembra** uma situação parecida a semana passada.*

   Um sinónimo aqui é *faz lembrar* (ou *faz recordar*).

Por outro lado, no sentido de "reviver", "recordar" é mais idiomático (mas *lembrar* também é possível). Isto aplica-se a "recordar alguma coisa", não a "relembrar alguma coisa a alguém"/"relembrar alguém de alguma coisa" ou "relembrar-se de alguma coisa".

> (17) *Foi esta etapa da vida do avô do actual Presidente da República, que esteve à frente do «Espadarte» em 1916 e do «Hidra» em 1919, que ontem se **recordou** no Alfeite.*
>   (18) *Passava os dias a **recordar** os tempos idos.*

Na frase (17), a substituição por "lembrar" não soa mal, mas em (18) seria ambígua -- "lembrar quem?". Estritamente falando, "recordar" também tem essa ambiguidade, mas "lembrar" é mais usado nessoutro sentido de "mencionar para que não seja esquecido".

Comment: Só umas achegas. Para exprimir nostalgia, *recordar* é mais idiomático que *lembrar*: "passava os dias a recordar os tempos idos." *Se bem se lembra* é mais comum que *se bem se recorda*, mas parece-me que em (9) são substituíveis. Não quererias era ter dois *recorda*.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, concordo, embora creia que o teu exemplo soe mal mais por ser ambíguo. Explico melhor na minha resposta.

Comment: `.. de me vir para aqui chatear-me` tem dois complementos indiretos. Devia ser ou "de me vir chatear" ou "de vir chatear-me".

Comment: @ANeves Não tenho a certeza, mas diria que está correta. O primeiro "me" é um [pronome de interesse](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/novamente-o-pronome-de-interesse-vai-me-a-casa/28990) ligado ao verbo "ir", o segundo indica quem está a ser chateado. Um exemplo semelhante: "Ele prometeu-me destruir-me". Sem o primeiro "me" poderia ter prometido a outra pessoa.

Comment: Bom, é verdade que no exemplo com "prometer" os "me"s não têm a mesma função. Mas `[func=".+\+<DAT"]{2}` no CETEMPúblico tem bons exemplos (entre muitos "deixe-me" mal anotados), como  "A admiração de Shelley por Godwin é tanta que, em 1814, escreve-lhe pedindo-lhe para o visitar."

Comment: Ah, percebo!... não me soa bem "me vir chatear-me", mas vejo que é uma possibilidade. Tem dois verbos, e gramaticalmente cada um dos verbos pode ter o seu próprio objeto indireto (portanto, dois "me"). Acho que são bons exemplos tanto "escreve-lhe pedindo-lhe" como "prometeu-me destrui-lo".

Comment: @Artefacto Não percebi o teu comentário. Na tua resposta parece-me que dizes que (18) está bem, mas se substituíssemos *recordar* por *lembrar* ficaria ambíguo (*passar os dias a lembrar* faz logo pensar em *passar os dias a chatear-me com alguma coisa*?) Mas eu só sugeri a versão com *recordar*.

Comment: @Jacinto A ideia que queria dar era que que substituir "recordar" por "lembrar" em (18) nao soa tão bom  porque se presta a essa ambiguidade, ao contrário de (17). Mudei (17) para o significado de "recordar" ser o mesmo ("reviver").

Comment: obrigado pelas vossas explicações: quando fiz um pesquisa Google a única coisa que encontrei foi uma citação: "..Seu erro fundamental é lembrar em vez de recordar. Há uma diferença entre lembrar e recordar; recordar é reviver, lembrar é apenas saber. O que é recordado fica, o que é lembrado é também esquecido" (Fernando Sabino, O Encontro Marcado)

Answer (score 9):

Uma resposta na [pergunta citada pelo Earthliŋ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154337/whats-the-difference-between-recall-and-remember) mostra uma diferença simples e bem objetiva:

> Recall cannot be used in the sense of not forget to do

<sup>Recordar não é usado no sentido de não esquecer</sup>

*Recordar* também me passa a impressão de algo de maior intensidade subjetiva que simplesmente *lembrar*. Por sinal, a etimologia da palavra remete a *coração* (em latim, *cordis*).

Comment: Embora curta a resposta aqui parece ser a mais precisa. Lembrar é muito usada no dia-a-dia por conta das situações cotidianas "lembrei que tenho hora no dentista", "lembrei que hoje é o última dia para me inscrever". Recordar é mais usada quando uma pessoa fala de fatos do passado

Comment: Não creio que seja nada precisa. A resposta sugere (mas nem sequer o diz explicitamente) que "recall" = "recordar". Mas isto não é verdade. Uma pessoa pode recordar alguém de algo, mas não podemos "recall someone". "Recordar" tem alguns (mas não todos) os signifiados de "remind". Para mais, "Recordar não é usado no sentido de não esquecer" também não é uma boa tradução. A correcta seria "Recordar não é usado no sentido de não se esquecer". Pelo menos em Portugal "esquecer algo" <> "esquecer-se de algo", ou melhor, "esquecer-se de algo" pode significar "esquecer algo", mas não vice-versa.

Comment: Além disso, resposta omite outros significados que "lembrar" tem que "recordar" não pode tomar. "Recordar não é usado no sentido de não se esquecer" é apenas o ponto 1. da minha resposta

Answer (score 3):

**"lembrar"** é o verbo que se usa na maioria das vezes e é um **verbo bitransitivo.**

- Eu (me) lembrei de trazer minha câmera.
- Ela não deve (se) lembrar mais que você foi grosseiro naquele dia.
- Eu (me) lembro que não existia o metrô naquela época.
- Eu não consegui (me) lembrar da fórmula para resolver a equação.
- Ela tem Alzheimer e já não (se) lembra de mais nada.

"recordar" refere-se a lembrar(-se) de fatos e ocorrências antigas. Você não recorda a fórmula, não recorda de trazer a câmera. Mas recorda que...

- Eu me recordo que não existia o metrô naquela época. (correto, embora menos usado que "lembrar")
- Ela tem Alzheimer e já não se recorda de mais nada. (correto)
- Eu não consegui recordar a fórmula.... (gramaticalmente correto mas, do ponto de vista semântico,
  soa muito estranho)
- "recordar é viver" (uma expressão muito usada e não podemos usar "lembrar" nesse caso.)
- "Ele recuperou os sentidos mas não se recorda de nada." (correto e ligeiramente mais acadêmico do que "lembrar")