# A regência do verbo lembrar

Tags: regência-verbal

Eu gostaria de tirar uma dúvida sobre a regência do verbo [*lembrar* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lembrar) no sentido *suscitar a lembrança de alguém*.

Salvo engano, são corretas as frases 1 e 2.

> 1. Lembrei ao João o seu dever. (Lembrei-lhe o seu dever.)
> 2. Lembrei ao João que tinha um dever. (Lembrei-lhe que tinha um dever.)

Mas são corretas também as frases 3 e 4?

> 3. Lembrei o João do seu dever. (Lembrei-o do seu dever.)
> 4. Lembrei o João de que tinha um dever. (Lembrei-o de que tinha um dever.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todas as tuas frases estão corretas. Se vires [*lembrar* no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar) encontrarás exemplos análogos. O sentido em que usas *lembrar* [(Priberam 1)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lembrar) divide-se no Aulete entre os sentidos 2 e 3 (as letras entre colchetes itálicos, *[a], [b]*, etc. são adições minhas para referenciar os exemplos):

> **3.** Advertir, avisar, prevenir [tdi. + a, de : *[a] O juiz lembrou ao jogador que na próxima falta seria expulso*] [tdr. + de : *[b] Lembrou o empregado de suas obrigações*]
>
> **4.** Mencionar (algo) a (alguém), para que não seja esquecido [tdi. + a : *[c] Lembrou ao marido que a conta de luz tinha que ser paga*] [tdr. + de : *[d] Lembrei-o do documento que tinha que assinar.*]

O teu exemplo (2) é análogo aos exemplos *[a]* e *[c]*. O teu exemplo (3) é análogo a *[b]* e *[d]*. O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) tem um exmplo análogo a (1) — «*lembrou ao amigo a antiga promessa*» — e o dicinário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, um análogo a (4) — «*lembrou o irmão de que lhe devia dinheiro*».

De qualquer modo, do ponto de vista do uso de *lembrar*, não há diferença entre os exemplos (1) e (2) ou entre (3) e (4). Em (1) tens uma única oração com um complemento direto, *o seu dever;* em (2) em vez do complemento direto tens uma oração subordinada substantiva objetiva direta — *que tinha um dever* — que desempenha o papel de complemento direto de *lembrar*. Em (3) e (4) é a mesma coisa, mas aí é complemento indireto e oração subordinada substantiva objetiva indireta. Para mais sobre este tipo de relação entre frases vê [esta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/16/deve-se-evitar-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-entre-ora%C3%A7%C3%B5es-subordinadas-substantivas-e-a-ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o-p/1429#1429).

Para uma discussão mais completa dos vários significados de *lembrar*, comparando com *recordar*, vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/lembrar-vs-recordar).

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Jacinto. Pelo que eu entendi, "Lembrei ao João o seu dever" é gramaticalmente certo, mas não faz muito sentido, porque não parece um aviso, certo?

Comment: Tu quiseste dizer "mas aí é complemento INdireto", né? Só para eu não criar mais confusão hehe.

Comment: @Akitirija Faz sentido. O que permite distinguir entre os dois sentidos do Aulete, aviso e prevenir esquecimento, é o contexto. Compara: «lembrei ao João o seu dever, porque ele já estava esquecido» e «lembrei ao João  o seu dever, porque ele já se estava a preparar para o não cumprir».

Comment: @Akitirija Exatamente. Vou corrigir.

Comment: @Akitirija Ainda reltivamente ao sentido, repara que os dois sentidos do aulete permitem as duas construções: *lembrar **a** alguém qualquer coisa* e *lembra alguém **de** qualquer coisa*.