# Regência do verbo lembrar - comentando um post na rede social Linkedin

Tags: regência

Vi a frase a seguir na rede social Linkedin.

[image]

Quando fui fazer um comentário e fiquei com dúvida na regência do verbo lembrar.

Exemplo:

> I) Tem razão, é bom lembrar-se dessa liberdade :). Para nos fazer esquecê-la existem muitas pessoas.
>
> II) Tem razão, é bom lembrar dessa liberdade :). Para nos fazer esquecê-la existem muitas pessoas.
>
> III) Tem razão, é bom nos lembrar dessa liberdade :). Para nos fazer esquecê-la existem muitas pessoas.
>
> IV) Tem razão, é bom lembrar essa liberdade :). Para nos fazer esquecê-la existem muitas pessoas.

Qual seria a melhor opção? Por quê?

Comment: Não exatamente uma resposta à tua pergunta, mas encontrarás uma pergunta semelhante (regência de "esquecer")  em http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/esqueci-or-me-esqueci onde há uma boa resposta de Artefacto.

Comment: Ok, vou ler. Agradeço pela indicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Lembrar*** tem muitas regências possíveis. As regências ideais dependem do que queres dizer exatamente. Apresento aqui as que me parecem relevantes para a tua pergunta.

**1. ‘manter na memória, pensar em’―*lembrar algo:***

> (IV) é bom lembrar essa liberdade
> é bom lembrarmos essa liberdade

Portanto aqui estarias  dizer, por exemplo, que as pessoas que mantêm na sua mente a liberdade tiram daí prazer, ou que é bom para a sociedade que nós mantenhamos a liberdade nas nossas mentes, ou até que é um dever nosso manter a liberdade nas nossa mentes.

Encontramos esta regência para este sentido em vários dicionários:

> lembrar bons momentos/a infância [(Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)
> Lembrou o tempo em que vivia no Rio [(Michaelis 2)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=V4pez)
> lembravam a figura do João com saudade (Houaiss, Lisboa, 2003)

**2.** Parecido com o anterior, mas com mais ênfase em **‘não esquecer’** ou em **‘trazer à ideia, à atenção consciente’―*lembrar-se de algo:***

> é bom nos lembrarmos dessa liberdade / é bom lembrarmo-nos dessa liberdade

É também possível *é bom lembrar-se dessa liberdade* para dar um conselho a alguém:

> (I) é bom [você/o senhor] lembrar-se dessa liberdade

Exemplos com esta regência e sentido:

> já não se lembrava de onde tinha posto a chave [(Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)
> Como vai a senhora, dona Alice? Lembra-se de mim? [(Michaelis 2)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=V4pez)

Eu encontro com este sentido no Google Books *lembrar de algo* (II, “é bom lembrar dessa liberdade”). A mim soa-me estranho, porque é uma regência que não se ouve em Portugal. Também não a encontro nos dicionários. Poderá ser uma regência que seja aceite apenas coloquialmente no Brasil.

**3. ‘chamar a atenção a alguém para’―*lembrar a alguém algo* ou *lembrar alguém de algo:***

> é bom [você] nos lembrar essa liberdade
> (III) é bom [você] nos lembrar dessa liberdade

*Lembrar alguém* e *lembrar a alguém* ficam iguais quando o *alguém* somos “nós”. Aqui estarias a dizer que foi bom que a pessoa que postou a mensagem nos tivesse lembrado a/da liberdade. A minha primeira impressão foi que não era este o sentido que pretendias, pois a frase não me soava muito bem sem explicitar o sujeito que lembra. Mas vendo melhor o contexto, provavelmente até é mesmo isto que queres.

Já temos uma pergunta sobre a regência nesta aceção: [*lembrei ao João o seu dever / lembrei o João do seu dever*.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/a-reg%C3%AAncia-do-verbo-lembrar) Exemplos das duas regências neste sentido:

> ***lembrar a alguém algo***
> O rapaz lembrou ao pai o trato que haviam feito [(Michaelis 1)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=V4pez)
> lembrou ao marido que a conta de luz tinha que ser paga [(Aulete 4)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)
>
> ***lembrar alguém de algo***
> Lembrou o empregado de suas obrigações [(Aulete 3)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)
> Lembrei-o do documento que tinha que assinar [(Aulete 4)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lembrar)

---

Eu foquei aqui apenas as aceções que me parecem relevantes para os teus exemplos e contexto. *Lembrar* pode ser usado com várias outras conotações. [Nesta pergunta sobre *lembrar vs recordar*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/lembrar-vs-recordar) encontras uma discussão mais abrangente, mas naturalmente não dirigida à tua pergunta em particular.

Comment: "Lembrar a alguém algo" (em que "algo" é o sujeito) também pode significar "não se esquecer": "não me lembram os pormenores".

Comment: @Artefacto É verdade, mas não lembraria ao diabo essa aceção no contexto desta pergunta, creio. Mas juntei uma nota a limitar o âmbito da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Embora todas as quatro formas sejam encontradas "no campo", a regência correta de lembrar é: quem lembra, lembra *alguém* de *alguma coisa*. Então o correto, de acordo com a norma culta, é:

> Tem razão, é bom [você] nos lembrar dessa liberdade.

Ou

> Tem razão, é bom [nós] nos lembrarmos dessa liberdade.

No segundo caso, é claro, a lembrança se torna mais genérica: é bom que as pessoas se lembrem, em vez de ser bom o interlocutor lembrar as pessoas (da liberdade).

Comment: Ou *lembra a alguém alguma coisa*

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que todas são gramaticalmente aceitas como corretas. Porém, se eu fosse comentar, utilizaria nessa ordem considerando Pt-BR.

- II
- III
- I
- IV